# Monitoring completed status of a remote cmd.exe process

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmic, tableau-api

I am running a .bat file in computer A from computer B by using my form application using WMI to publish dash boards. The .bat file calls a command line utility tabcmd.exe multiple times and utility updates log file in computer A in the below location  **"C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Tableau\tabcmd.log"**

I want to update my form application with the log file details in Computer B once the process is completed in computer A.
I am running the .bat file by using like below,

```
        String path = @"C:\tabcmd.bat";
        String machineName = textBox1.Text;            
        var processToRun = new[] { path  };
        var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Username = textBox3.Text;
        connection.Password = textBox2.Text;
        var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", machineName), connection);
        var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
        wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
```

This .bat file publishes dashboards in computer B based on dynamic datasource parameters, so the run-time of the .bat file is unpredictable, in this case how do I ensure that .bat file is run or the updating log file is completed.

Is there any way to monitor this process by process ID? if so I can read the log file once my process is completed. the below is not helping me in this situation since cmd.exe is still running in the target computer A.

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process prc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(10100, "CHORRL0110")
  prc.WaitForExit ()
```

Thanks for your help!